# why the getElementById() method isn't working right

Tags: javascript, html

I´m learning, so I want to make a button do something, for now, just show a message with the alert function. But it isn't working, I think the method getElementById is not working and I don't know why.

here is the javascript code:

```
function button(){
let btn = document.getElementById("sub");
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    alert("clicked");
});
}
```

And I'm calling the function in the html file, with the onclick property, here is the code:

```
<button class="btn" id="sub" onclick="button()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Have you checked the your browser's console for errors? Nte that you don't need the event listener part if you're using `onclick="button()"`. That will call the function.

Comment: Use ```var``` instead of ```let``` and it will work

Comment: the alert message shows up the second time when you click the button. Why do you need to add a listener when you already have `onclick="button()"`

Comment: @Mr.Phantom — what? Changing `let` to `var` will make _no_ difference, and `let` and `const` are preferred over `var`.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen when you assigned an onclick and then assigned an additional event listener within the code being called when you clicked the button? Are you just looking for the alert or something else?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "Not working" is pretty broad

Answer (score 2):

You either need to attach an event listener to the button to listen for the click - or to have the call to the function in the onclick handler - but not both. If you have both then you are effectively saying - when I click the button - ad an event listener to the button to listen for another click....

It is usually recommended to separate the js from the html and have the event listener in the js and not have an onclick handler.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("sub");

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" id="sub" >Submit</button>
```

Ff you really want to have the onclick handler - then you don't need the getElementByID()... - you just call the function directly in the onclick(). But I would not do it that way....

```js
function buttonClicked(){
  alert("clicked");
};
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" id="sub" onclick="buttonClicked()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want *either*

```js
function buttonHandler() {
    alert("clicked");
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="sub" onclick="buttonHandler()">Submit</button>
```

*or*

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("sub");
btn.addEventListener('click', function buttonHandler() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="sub">Submit</button>
```

but not a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

Please redefine your function `button()`. You already listening the `click` event writing the `onclick` inline attribute:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" id="sub" onclick="button()">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
function button(){
    //let btn = document.getElementById("sub");
    alert("clicked");
}
```